# Using Javascript Executor to select from a Select tag

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am having difficulty with a tricky Select which won't work with usual Selenium api methods.  So, I have to use Javascript executor.  I am so far, unable to correctly select the options from the dropdown = Where from? and What destination?

With the below code, the page seems to refresh when I click 'Search'.  Perhaps, the css selector passed to the JS is wrong?

Website under test is: https://club18-30.com/club18-30

```
private String whereFromText = "LGW"
private String whereToText = "IBZ"

    public void setDepartureAirport(String whereFromText)
    selectOption(whereFromText);
}

    public void setDestinationAirport(String whereToText) {
    selectOption(whereToText);
}

    public void submitSearchRequest() throws InterruptedException {
    By searchButtonLocator = By.xpath(searchButtonLocatorPath);
    click(searchButtonLocator);

    By searchResultsLocator = By.xpath(searchResultsLocatorPath);
    waitForIsDisplayed(searchResultsLocator, 180);
}


 public void selectOption(String option) {
    String script =
            "function selectOption(s) {\r\n" +
                    "   var sel = document.querySelector('.custom-select-options');\r\n" +
                    "   for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++)\r\n" +
                    "   {\r\n" +
                    "       if (sel.options[i].text.indexOf(s) > -1)\r\n" +
                    "       {\r\n" +
                    "           sel.options[i].selected = true;\r\n" +
                    "           break;\r\n" +
                    "       }\r\n" +
                    "   }\r\n" +
                    "}\r\n" +
                    "return selectOption('" + option + "');";

    javaScriptExecutor(script);
}
```

Comment: Your application ask for credential. Could you provide the credential or give us the HTML?

Comment: @Buaban - there are no credentials? I do not see credentials anywhere

Comment: You may save the credential or your machine may be in the same domain so it automatically authen.

Comment: My apologies - I have updated the URL

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is almost correct except the CssSelector expression. It should be `".destinationAirport .custom-select"` for destination airport and `".arrivalAirport .custom-select"` for arrival airport. However, I've tried with js but the app shows error when click submit button. So you may need to click and select the value on GUI. See code below:

```
String destination = "Glasgow - Scotland (GLA) United Kingdom";
String arrival = "Ibiza - Balearic Islands (IBZ) Spain";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".destinationAirport .custom-select")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'destinationAirport')]//li[text()='" + destination + "']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".arrivalAirport .custom-select")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'arrivalAirport')]//li[text()='" + arrival + "']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".searchButton")).click();
```

Comment: THank you for the reply. Unfortunately, the page seems to refresh after selection the destination airport and thus the script fails. Not sure what else to try!

Comment: @Steerpike This script works well on my machine (jdk8, chrome). What browser do you use?

Comment: I have tried on latest chrome and firefox and also using Java 8, page refreshes and fails to search

Comment: @Steerpike The code still works fine on my machine. Can you show your new code? What airport do you select?